# Browser for Office VBA (not365)

Tags: excel, vba, browser

Enterprise Windows10-64bit desktop Excel 64-bit 2019 VBA uses only Internet Explorer for

```
Dim objie As New internetexplorer, HexColor$, celValue$
...
objie.Document.Write HTML$
```

It is getting flaky finding a combination of Windows10 and IE11 that actually works (renders the browser).
I understand Selenium may provide access from VBA to other modern browsers.

1. Which Win10 and IE11 combinations work?
2. Which version of Selenium or other open-source have been security-checked?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe just security setting in`Internet-options`? I have no problems using IE11 and Win 10 (latest Updates) with Office-Vba (x86) and intercept events from IE (WithEvents). Show your Problems (image?) and config of Internet-Options.

Comment: Did I missunderstood you, by assuming`Internetexplorer`Object not working on Office x64? If pages are just poor rendered, you just didn't change the [rendering mode](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version)?